# jQuery on click behaves differently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating html elements according to some condition i receive from server response.

```
@if($candidate->status == "new")
   @if($candidate->priority == "")
   <a id = "prioritize" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}" ><img id = "priority" src="icons/non_priority.png"></img></a>
   @else if($candidate->priority == "yes")
   <a id = "prioritize" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}" ><img id = "priority" src="icons/priority.png"></img></a>
   @endif 
@endif
```

and few more like this with same inner if conditions

```
@if($candidate->status == "scheduled")
@endif

@if($candidate->status == "good")
@endif

@if($candidate->status == "bad")
@endif
```

The `on click` function works only on elements that are populated when "new" condtion is satisfied.

```
@if($candidate->status == "new")
@endif
```

and doesn't work on other elements that are populated by other conditions. But when i comment of `new` condition. Someother condition like "**good**" or "**bad**" or "**scheduled**" works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#favorite').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).find('img').attr('src','icons/non_star.png')) {

            var candidate_id = $(this).data('value');
            alert(candidate_id);
    }
});

$('#prioritize').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).find('img').attr('src','icons/non_priority.png')) {

            var candidate_id = $(this).data('value');
            alert(candidate_id);
    }
});

});
```

I don't understand the issue behind this though all the id's clicked are same.

Answer (score 0):

An html id is unique. You should use à class attribute. 
Change id by class and in your jquery change #id by .class.

.attr( attributeName, value ) is used to set attribute value and not test her. 
Use .attr(attributeName) === 'value'
You can also add data-* attribute to this test for a solution more sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `class` for html elements that can appear multiple times because `id`s are always unique for html elements. Add class and change your code as below

```
$('.favorite').on('click',function(){
if ($(this).find('img').attr('src','icons/non_star.png')) {

        var candidate_id = $(this).data('value');
        alert(candidate_id);
}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think either you should give the different IDs to the  elements depending on their status or you should call them using their class names.